# secure MY rest services which are consumed in MY Android and iPhone App

Tags: .net, wcf, security, rest

The rest services will be consumed only by my Apps(can I call the web services an API?).
The users will log in using their email and password.
Should I implement somethin as complicated as WIF ([a way to extend WIF to rest](http://blog.jayway.com/2012/01/05/secure-your-rest-based-wcf-service-with-wif-part-1/)), or what security method would you recommend given that the services will be consumed only in my App?

Are there any Azure services that I can use to avoid impleenting SSL for my WCF rest service?

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need WIF for REST at all.

Organically for REST are perfectly fitting OAuth and OpenID. By released version of WIF for on-premise hosting there are no OAuth. There are some libraries to integrate WIF with OAuth for on-premise but they are still in beta.

For cloud hosting look at [Azure Access Control Service](http://acs.codeplex.com/).

Anyway you can use OAuth or OpenID for your on-premise hosted services.
Look at [oauth.net](http://oauth.net/) and [DotNetOpenAuth library](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/)